# Что такое дейтаграммы (Datagram)?

Tags: java, терминология

> Сетевое взаимодействие по протоколу ТСР /IP подходит для большинства сетевых
>   нужд. Оно обеспечивает сериализируемые, предсказуемые и надежные потоки
>   ввода-вывода пакетов данных. Но все это обходится совсем не даром. Протокол
>   ТСР включает в себя немало сложных алгоритмов адаптации к перегруженности
>   сетей, а также самые пессимистические предположения относительно потери
>   пакетов. Это в какой-то степени делает неэффективным способ переноса данных
>   по сети. Альтернативой ему служат **дейтаграммы**.

Что такое дейтаграммы?

Comment: Датаграмма - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0 И протокол UDP - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP

Answer (score 2):

[Источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)

> `Датаграмма` (англ. datagram, дейтаграмма) — блок информации, передаваемый протоколом без предварительного установления соединения и создания виртуального канала. Любой протокол, не устанавливающий предварительное соединение (а также обычно не контролирующий порядок приёмо-передачи и дублирование пакетов), называется датаграммным протоколом. Таковы, например, протоколы `Ethernet`, `IP`, `UDP` и др. Название «датаграмма» было выбрано по аналогии со словом телеграмма.